# Saving WebView with Canvas drawing

Tags: android, android-webview, android-canvas

I'm trying to save as an image the contents of a WebView with a canvas drawing on top of it. I've tried two methods:

```
Picture picture = drawView.capturePicture();
Bitmap bmp = pictureDrawable2Bitmap(new PictureDrawable(picture)); 
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
    getContentResolver(), bitmap,
    "image" + ".png", "drawing");

 private static Bitmap pictureDrawable2Bitmap(PictureDrawable pictureDrawable){
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() ,pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture());
        return bitmap;
 }
```

This gets me the entire WebView page but without the Canvas drawing.

Method 2:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawView.getWidth(), drawView.getHeight(),
                     Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawView.draw(canvas);
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
 getContentResolver(), bitmap,
     "image" + ".png", "drawing");
      drawView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

This way I get both the canvas and WebView but it only captures it at the current zoom level. Which means if I save it while zoomed in it will only save the current view state, not the entire image. It's also lower quality.

Any suggestion on how to get them together?

Some of the code:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w + 1500, h + 1500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
    canvas.save();
    //canvas.translate(clipBounds.left, clipBounds.top);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(8/mScaleFactor);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, 0, 0);
     if(!pathsDrawn) {
           canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
           pathsDrawn = true;
 }
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

WebView settings:

```
    final DrawingView drawView;
    drawView = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.pdf);
    drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = drawView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    String data = "someurl.jpg"
    drawView.loadUrl(data);     
    drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Picture picture = drawView.capturePicture();
            Bitmap bmp = pictureDrawable2Bitmap(new PictureDrawable(picture));
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), overlayMark(bmp, DrawingView.canvasBitmap),
                    "dfdsf" + ".png", "drawing");
```

***EDIT****
Got it working for the most part. I basically drew two bitmaps with canvas. However, the web image bitmap and the drawing bitmap do not scale correctly. I had to offset this by scaling the drawing using a Matrix and redrawing the bitmap before overlaying it on the web bitmap. For some reason, scale it to 1.5f makes it line up perfectly, at least on the 10in tablet I'm testing it on. If anyone has any more insight on this or how to make it better let me know.

```
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
Picture picture = drawView.capturePicture();
Bitmap bmp = pictureDrawable2Bitmap(new PictureDrawable(picture));
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(DrawingView.canvasBitmap, 0, 0, DrawingView.canvasBitmap.getWidth(), DrawingView.canvasBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), overlayMark(bmp, resizedBitmap),
                    "dfdsf" + ".png", "drawing");

 private static Bitmap pictureDrawable2Bitmap(PictureDrawable pictureDrawable){
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() ,pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawPicture(pictureDrawable.getPicture());
        return bitmap;
 }

private Bitmap overlayMark(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)    { 
       int bh = bmp1.getHeight();
       int bw = bmp1.getWidth();
       Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bw,bh,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay); 
       canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
       return bmOverlay;
    }
```

Comment: Just download the image and then show it in the WebView. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Download it, create a bitmap and set that Bitmap to the canvas?

Comment: Your code says `String data = "someurl.jpg"` which means you are showing a jpg image in the WebView. Why don't you download it, save it, and finally show it in the WebView (using the local copy). You can even use an ImageView with PinchZoom abilities.

Comment: I did an overlay of two bitmaps. Check my edit

Comment: Is your tablet set as an HDPI device? This may explain the 1.5f scaling factor.